# Unfurling, Nesting or Cascading URLs in an environment.ts file

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

I am developing an Angular application and would like to create environment.ts files so that I can use different APIs for calls to the development backend services vs production backend services.

I would like to reuse and append properties that are already set onto and in properties that follow like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'https://remote.apiurl.com',

  accountsUrl: `${baseUrl}` + 'accounts/',

};
```

such that accessing environment.accountsUrl will give "https://remote.apiurl.com/accounts/"

I have tried using this. and jquery ${} as above.

Answer (score 0):

I was assisted by a colleague and I hope it is acceptable to answer this question here as well.

environment.ts

```
const apiBaseUrl: string = 'https://remote.apiurl.com';
const accountsBaseUrl: string = apiBaseUrl + 'accounts/';

export const environment = {
  production: false,

  accounts: {
    getAddUrl() {
      return accountsBaseUrl + 'add/';
    },

    ...
  }

};
```

So I can now access the concatenated string anywhere as

```
addAccountUrl = env.accounts.getAddUrl();
```